# Next JS refresh not working for Layout components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

in my Next js app i used layout and created a sidebar. but when i make any changes it doesn't display unless i kill all node and start `npm run dev`. but in my `index` file it works fine.

in my `_app.js`

```
return (
      <Layout>
        <Component {...pageProps} />
      </Layout>
  )
```

in `Layout.js`

```
return (
    <div className=" flex ">
        <Sidebar />
        <main>{children}</main>
    </div>
)
```

and `sidebar.js`

```
const [open, setOpen] = useState(true)
    return (
        <div className={` h-screen duration-300 ${ open? "w-72" : "w-20"} relative bg-slate-800`}>
            <button className=' bg-red-500' onClick={()=> setOpen(!open)} >CLICK ME</button>
        </div>
    )
```

while running `npm run dev` it throws an error.

```
warn  - Fast Refresh had to perform a full reload. Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/fast-refresh#how-it-works
error - unhandledRejection: Error: aborted
    at connResetException (node:internal/errors:692:14)
    at abortIncoming (node:_http_server:602:17)
    at socketOnClose (node:_http_server:596:3)
    at Socket.emit (node:events:539:35)
    at TCP.<anonymous> (node:net:709:12) {
  code: 'ECONNRESET'
}
```

why is this happening and what is the fix?